# Parse JSON in lighting:outputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have some Text fields on an object that are storing values in a JSON array.
`["value1", "value2"...]`
We want to display these values in a custom lighting component. The natural thing to do would be:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="MyObject__c">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="MyJsonField__c"/>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

The problem is that there the output is in a JSON format (because that's the string in the field). We want to just display the list of values `value1, value2...`.
Is there a way to do that in Salesforce? Something like `lightning:formattedNumber` but for JSON? That will work in `lightning:outputField`?

Comment: Might help you [Using JSON in Lightning Component default attribute, and have it be parsable via JSON.parse](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207228/using-json-in-lightning-component-default-attribute-and-have-it-be-parsable-via)

Comment: That's an interesting question/answer but not relevant at all to my issue. I want a way, in markup, to pretify and display the content of a JSON array. Possibly similar to a JSON pipe (`|json`) that shows up in many other modern frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning doesn't have the same notion of pipes or formatters that are present in other templating frameworks. You'll have to do the heavy lifting yourself. `<lightning:outputField>` does take the data type of the sObject field into account when it renders data, but Salesforce does not have a JSON field type - so that component doesn't know how to handle it.

Reworking to display a formatted notion of a JSON field is going to require you to go outside the `<lightning:recordViewForm>` layer here, and hence may cost you more code.

One possibility would be to establish a new component attribute,

```
<aura:attribute name="formattedJSON" type="String" />
```

and a change handler

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.ATTRIBUTE_WHERE_JSON_IS }" action="{! c.formatJSON}" />
```

where in your controller you consume the JSON and populate it into `v.formattedJSON`, which can then be rendered with `<lightning:formattedText>`:

```
formatJSON: function(component, event, handler) {
    component.set('v.formattedJSON', JSON.parse(component.get('v.ATTRIBUTE_WHERE_JSON_IS')).join(', '));
},
```

To have the JSON available in an attribute, you'd have to implement `<force:recordData>`, separately query it from the server, or take some similar tactic.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. It's frustrating that I have these pre-built components, but I still need to write tons of code.